# How to display public variables in another form

Tags: vb.net

I've already searched this up many times but none of them worked for me so please help. The code I've been trying to use is:

```
'Making the variables public in form2
Public Module GlobalVariables
    'Making the variables public 
    Public Property Juvenplp As Integer
    Public Property Adultplp As Integer
    Public Property Senileplp As Integer
    Public Property Juvensr As Single
    Public Property Adultsr As Single
    Public Property Senilesr As Single
    Public Property Birthrate As Single
    Public Property genmore As Integer
    Public Property i As Integer
End Module
```

Displaying then in Form4

```
Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    InitializeComponent()
    GlobalVariables.Juvenplp = Me.Label7.Text
    GlobalVariables.Adultplp = Me.Label8.Text
    GlobalVariables.Senileplp = Me.Label9.Text
    GlobalVariables.Juvensr = Me.Label10.Text
    GlobalVariables.Adultsr = Me.Label11.Text
    GlobalVariables.Senilesr = Me.Label12.Text
    GlobalVariables.Birthrate = Me.Label14.Text
End Sub
```

The problem is that they're not being displayed.

Comment: Not being displayed? Is that because your setting the variable rather than the label? So instead of `GlobalVariables.Juvenplp = Me.Label7.Text` you would do `Me.Label7.Text = GlobalVariables.Juvenplp`.

Comment: what is that `Public Module GlobalVariables`? Does your code compile with it?

Comment: Is this VBA????? Your public vars are set up incorrectly and your passing the values to a text box, not the other way around.  Properties will exist in an object, you are saying variables and defining a property, so just say public strMyVar as string, then me.textbox1.text=strMyVar.  In VBA modules are public, you have the `option private module` option

Comment: The question is about VB.Net. [Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner so just testing VB out.

Comment: I redid it so it looks like this now but it still won't display it:                                                            
        Label7.Text = GlobalVariables.Juvenplp

Comment: user3598756 I copied it from a post and it seems to be working

Comment: `InitializeComponent()` has no business being used from a TextChanges event